# cost vs no.of queries snowflakes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Say I have warehouse A with 5 queries running between 1PM to 2PM and it cost me X credits.If I  increase the no.of queries from 5 to 10 in the same time window does that cost me X+X=2X credits?(provided that all 10 are not same queries).

Load on the warehouse

[image]

Credits used for the warehouse during the same time frame.

[image]

Details of credit used form WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY

[image]

Comment: Justification that the suggested post not related to this:
Here I am trying to find out if you load the warehouse with additional queries will it in turn increases the credit usage or not ?but the suggested link has answer that confirms the credits are charged based on the warehouse time,which is not related to what i have asked far(no.of queries).

Answer (score 0):

To reduce credit you have to use WH effectively,  if 2X queries are getting executed with in the same time-frame using same Warehouse , without increasing WH size then you will **be charged the same amount**. # of executions will not incur cost, cost will incur for WH up-time

Even if your warehouse can bear the load of nX queries within the same time frame you should use that. These are some common consideration for optimized credit usage

- Grouping Queries together
- Maximum utilization of WH up time
- Minimizing  WH Idle time

Comment: But the output i captured is not reflecting the statement                                                                                           "# of executions will not incur cost",Please see the screen shots pasted now in the original question.if the credits used does not depends   load/no.of queries executed why would we see more credits used at 9 AM (in pic 2) than what we see at 10 AM and 11 AM?.Also we see the credits_used is varying(in pic 3) for each hour. Is Credits used by warehouse  is directly proportional to load ?no.of queries.? Please clarify me

Comment: Hi,  "# of executions will not incur cost, cost will incur for WH up-time"  this means , even if the WH is idle not running any query, you may need to pay the bill for up-time. Now why it would be active after query execution because of the Auto Suspend  parameters set.

Comment: Iam in line with you on WH uptime vs  cost .But I see credits used also depends on load  and no.of  queries ,based on the output collected above.  question :" why would we see more credits used at 9 AM (in pic 2) than what we see at 10 AM and 11 AM?."if its  just depends on up time and not the load?

Comment: Can someone comment on this. I am trying to understand, is load directly proportional to cost?

Comment: Warehouse uptime will cost you not number of queries that got executed. You can keep the warehouse up without executing any query, that will still cost you. The wh credit consumption would be different in these scenarios, try to execute 12 different queries sequencially , in parallel or in a gap of 5 minutes. Keep your warehouse auto suspend time as 5 minutes , then validate.